# Change Linux network setup

Tags: linux, networking

I'm working on some software, that runs on a Centos 5.xx installation. I'ts not allowed for our customers to log in to Linux, everything is done from Windows applications, developed by us.

So we have build a frontend for the user to configure network setup: Static/DHCP, ip-address, gateway, DNS, Hostname.

Right now I let the user enter the information in the Windows app, and then write it on the Linux server like this:

- Write to /etc/resolv.conf: Nameserver
- Write to /etc/sysconfig/network: Gateway and Hostname
- Write to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0: Ipaddress, Netmask, Bootproto(DHCP or Static)
  I also (after some time) found out that I was unable to send mail, unless I wrote in /etc/hosts: 127.0.0.1 Hostname

All this seems to work, but is there a better/easier way to do this?

Also, I read the network configuration nearly the same way, but if I use DHCP, I miss som information, for instance the Ip-address. I know that I can get some information from the commandline (ifconfig), but I dont get for instance Hostname, Gateway and DNS. Is there a commandline tool that will display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing writing the information, but you'll need to go to the command line to read the information like you said.

the IP is gotten from `ip addr show <interface>` or `ip addr show all` and parsing that. ifconfig is the slightly older command for this.

The default gateway is gotten from `ip route show` as well (route show or netstat -rn gives you the same information in a different format - ip is the newer command for configuring this)

DNS servers are practically always `/etc/resolv.conf`, so reading that should be fine. `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is where that is configured... by default `/etc/hosts` will override your DNS server settings.

Hostname is gotten through running `hostname`

Answer (score 1):

Webmin, probably. Although it being a web-based application I'm not sure it will work gracefully with all network configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm following the main part of your question, but the last part is fairly easy.  There is not 1 program that displays all that you are looking for but, `hostname` displays the current hostname, `netstat -r` will display network routing data & the default gateway, if it is set.  `dig` will display the currently used domain name server. Specifically:

```
dig `hostname` | grep SERVER
```

should return something like

```
;; SERVER: 68.94.156.1#53(68.94.156.1)
```